# Tables having one to many relationship generates outer join

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I have 2 tables

```cs
public class Department : DbContext
{
   public int DeptId {get; set;}
   public string DeptName {get; set;}
   public virtual List<Student> Students {get; set;}
}

public class Student: DbContext
{
   public int StudentId {get; set;}
   public string StudentName {get; set;}
   public int DeptId {get; set;}
   public virtual Department Department {get; set;}
}
```

So a department can have multiple students
But I want to join and convert all the data into below structure

```cs
public class CollegeData
{
   public int DeptId {get; set;}
   public string DeptName {get; set;}
   public List<StudentData> Students {get; set;}
}

public class StudentData
{
   public int StudentId {get; set;}
   public string StudentName {get; set;}
}
```

I wrote the below query to get the joined data

```cs
var data = (from dept in _dbContext.Department 
            select new CollegeData
            {
              DeptId = dept.DeptId,
              DeptName = dept.DeptName,
              Students = (from student in _dbContext.Student
                          where student.DeptId == dept.DeptId
                          select new StudentData
                          {
                             StudentId = student.StudentId,
                             StudentName = student.StudentName
                          }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

But when I am profiling this, it is creating left join query.
I will need inner join query in this use case

Can somebody give me a direction for this?

Comment: Having `.ToList()` in the middle of a LINQ query is a performance hit, as the server will not be able to do everything in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out a few things

- Is the FK relation made required or optional? Use `HasRequired` or `.IsRequired(true)` if the relation is required. Required relations might resolve to inner join. But the if type of property is collection , it might  translate to LEFT JOIN
- The 2nd option is to `add a null check in the condition` to filter out empty record and it essentially translates to INNER JOIN.